# C++ returning an object copy

Tags: c++, optimization, copy, copy-constructor, rvo

*I wrote the following code:*

```
class MyObjectHolder {
public:
    std::vector<int> getMyObject() const {
        return myObject;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> myObject;
};
```

At some point of my program I attempt to use the `getMyObject` method and use only `const` methods on the retrieved object:

```
const std::vector<int> myObject = myObjectHolder.getMyObject();
myObject.size();
int a = myObject.front();
```

- Now, is it possible that the compiler will optimize this code so that **no copies of the `std::vector<int>`** are done?

  > Is it somehow possible that the compiler determines that I'm only using the `const` methods on the retrieved object *(and let's assume there is no `mutable` nonsense happening behind it)* and it **would not make any copies** of the objects and perform these `const` operations on the `private` member of the `MyObjectHolder` instead?
- If yes, would it be possible if I didn't explicitly declare the `const std::vector<int> myObject` as `const`?
- If no, what are the reasons not to do this? In which cases this optimization would be to hard to implement / deduce that it's possible and correct here / etc... ?

Comment: [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) involves temporary objects. Unless I am missing something, there are no temporary objects here so no RVO.

Comment: @hmjd Right. I should not be talking about the `RVO` here, just about the possible optimization with using the `private` variable directly. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now, is it possible that the compiler will optimize this code so that no copies of the `std::vector<int>` are done?

No, the compiler doesn't know what callers will do with that object unless you are making use of global optimization over all code that uses the object (the compiler can't generally make assumptions about its use; moreover if object is exported from a dll it can't make any assumption at all).

> If yes, would it be possible if I didn't explicitly declare the const std::vector myObject as const?

No, anyway the conversion from non-const to const could be implicit.

> If no, what are the reasons not to do this? In which cases this optimization would be to hard to implement / deduce that it's possible and correct here / etc... ?

It's an optmiziation that should be done inside `getMyObject()` but the compiler can't be sure that callers won't cast away the const. Actually this is a very old debate about the use of `const`, usually I think it's more clear to always think about `const` as something for programmers and not for compilers.

Comment: "No, the compiler doesn't know what callers will do with that object." -> Is not generally correct. Proposed change: "Unless you are making use of global optimization over all codes that the object, the compiler can't generally make assumptions" or similar.

Comment: @phresnel you're right (edited), moreover if the object is exported it can't make any assumption (and I'm not sure it can even follow casts inside the same unit).

Comment: Even more so, the compiler is allowed to spit out multiple versions of the same function, which would mean an even more generalized edit :P

Comment: @phresnel modern compilers have too much freedom. good old times! LOL

Comment: Yes and no, really. Times where those where any half-decent programmer could optimize programs by just doing some inline-assembly. Nowadays it requires years of assembly experience to gain anything from it, haha.

Comment: @phresnel I was joking, I'm happy compilers (usually) can optimize code much more (and safer) than us.

Comment: On a side note: I think it would be great if OSs would provide a syscall to copy-on-write duplicate data. I.e. tell the OS "take this part of the address space here in my process, and mirror it there, but make an in-situ modified copy, if I write to it." The infrastructure for this is already present in most OSs, all it take was a new syscall to expose this functionality. Hmm… .oO(`cd /usr/src/linux/ ; vim …` ;)

Comment: @datenwolf yes but I guess it's a hard request for compiler writers, I'm not so sure it's something easy to implement on every platform (I'm thinking about Windows...)

Comment: @Adriano: I wouldn't see this as something for the compiler to take care of. The OPs request of passing the vector without making a copy could be implemented in the library as well (keeping a reference to the original vector and only when calling a non-const function making a copy). Now in such a library based implementation you'd have to go through a full copy, which is not very efficient if only a few elements are changed. A CoW copy could be created by the library through a syscall like "memcow" into a new vector object. Modification there would make it a real copy, otherwise just reference

Comment: @datenwolf yes, if something like that was supported to a lower level could be very nice and...we may stop to reinvent the wheel every time CoW is needed!!! Frankly I can't even imagine how to (easy) implement a generic "cow_new" because of aliases and pointers. Is there anything in any library for that? I do not remember anything reusable.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use

```
const std::vector<int>& getMyObject() const {
    return myObject;
}
```

It would return the constant reference of myObject without copy that.

And use the result with

```
const std::vector<int>& myObject = myObjectHolder.getMyObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible [Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) will kick in. If you use C++ compiler with [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) support, then you may get it optimised by [move semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors).

I'd recommend to read the excellent article [Want Speed? Pass by Value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) by Dave Abrahams with discussion in the comments below it.

However, for details you should refer documentation of your C++ compiler.