# Why RVO doesn't happen here?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

I have read Dave Abrahams [article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) on RVO and a few other Q/As on SO ([14043609](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043609/will-rvo-happen-when-returning-stdpair), [9293726](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293726/why-g-does-not-enable-rvo-here) and [10818278](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818278/c-returning-an-object-copy)) but I still have a question. When I compile and run the following code, I get this output:

```
Address of v in func    0x7fffac6df620
Address of v.data in func       0x2081010
Address of v in main    0x7fffac6df690
Address of v.data in func       0x20811b0
9
```

To me it seems that a copy is made. How do I pass large objects out of functions? Please note that I want to return one or more objects without writing an explicit structure for it. I used GCC 4.6.3 with -O2. Edit: The first two answers showed me that I expected too much from the compiler. I added a main2 that behaves in the same way, e.g. the printed addresses are different. I would like to emphasize that the motivation is efficient return of large objects.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> func() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(100);
  for (int k=0;k!=100;k+=1)
    v.push_back(k);

  double a = 5.0;
  std::cout << "Address of v in func\t" << &v << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << v.data() << std::endl;
  return make_tuple(v, a);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  double a;
  std::tie(v, a) = func();
  std::cout << "Address of v in main\t" << &v << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << v.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << v[9] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}


int main2() {
  auto tp = func();
  std::vector<int> & v = std::get<0>(tp);
  double & a = std::get<1>(tp);
  std::cout << "Address of v in main\t" << &v << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << v.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << v[9] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, there are two things that prevent RVO. The function doesn't return `v`, but instead a tuple that is constructed form `v` and `a`. Also in main function `v` is assigned and not constructed from the return value.

To get what you want you could use the tuples directly without additional vector objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> func() {
  std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> t;
  get<0>(t).reserve(100);
  for (int k=0;k!=100;k+=1)
    get<0>(t).push_back(k);

  get<1>(t) = 5.0;
  std::cout << "Address of v in func\t" << &get<0>(t) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << get<0>(t).data() << std::endl;
  return t;
}

int main()
{
  std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> t = func();
  std::cout << "Address of v in main\t" << &get<0>(t) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << get<0>(t).data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << get<0>(t)[9] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of v in func    0x28fe80
Address of v.data in func       0x962c08
Address of v in main    0x28fe80
Address of v.data in func       0x962c08
9
```

Alternative optimization is to use move semantics when constructing the tuple:

```
 return make_tuple(std::move(v), a);
```

In this case at least copying the vector's internal buffer is avoided:

```
Address of v in func    0x28fdd4
Address of v.data in func       0xa72c08
Address of v in main    0x28fe64
Address of v.data in func       0xa72c08
9
```

Answer (score 3):

Since both `v` and `a` have been declared as variables in `main()`, there is no copy to elide. What you get here is copy assignment, not copy construction. It is the equivalent of this:

```
struct Foo {};

Foo foo() { return Foo(); }

int main()
{
  Foo f1;
  f1 = foo();  // no copy hence f1 is distinct from object returned
  Foo f2 = foo(); // We can get RVO here, returned object can be f2.
}
```

Comment: I added a second example that should be equivalent to your code. However, it still does not use RVO. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

RVO may very well be happening here but the only opportunity for copy elision in the code you've given is copying the return value of `make_tuple(v, a)` into the return value of `func()`.

Regardless of whether this is done or not, the `std::vector` and `double` would still be copied. You are just assigning from the result of `func()` to `v` and `a` in `main`. Copy elision (and RVO) only apply to copy/move construction, not assignment.

When you do `&v` in `main`, you are just getting the address of the `v` object defined in the first line of `main`. Of course this is different from the `v` object defined in `func`.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example data is copied in the assignment :

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  double a;
  std::tie(v, a) = func();
```

In your second example, data is still copied when you make a tuple. This modified example shows that the RVO really happens :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> func() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(100);
  for (int k=0;k!=100;k+=1)
    v.push_back(k);

  double a = 5.0;

  const auto ret = make_tuple(v, a);
  const auto &v1 = std::get<0>(ret);

  std::cout << "Address of v in func\t" << &v1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << v1.data() << std::endl;

  return ret;
}

int main() {
  auto tp = func();
  std::vector<int> & v = std::get<0>(tp);
  double & a = std::get<1>(tp);
  std::cout << "Address of v in main\t" << &v << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << v.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << v[9] << std::endl;

  (void)a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I found Timo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387047/1693829) most helpful. This is how I adapted that answer to my own style. Note the duplicated boilerplate in both `func` and `main`. Of course, if someone knows how to get rid of that it would be great!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> func() {
  std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> tp;
  std::vector<int> & v = std::get<0>(tp);
  double & a = std::get<1>(tp);

  v.reserve(100);
  for (int k=0;k!=100;k+=1)
    v.push_back(k);

  a = 5.0;
  std::cout << "Address of v in func\t" << &v << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << v.data() << std::endl;
  return tp;
}

int main() {
  std::tuple<std::vector<int>, double> tp = func();
  std::vector<int> & v = std::get<0>(tp);
  double & a = std::get<1>(tp);

  std::cout << "Address of v in main\t" << &v << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Address of v.data in func\t" << v.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << v[9] << std::endl;

  (void)a;
  return 0;
}
```